# Increment id of td by Loop and getting id in function

Tags: php, html

I'm populating a table with database data, I want to get value of td that is row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7wDI.png), to perform action in PHP function, I don't know how to do this:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT name,c_no,email,speciality FROM doctor_temp";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
<?php $count=1; $count++;?>
                   <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>
                   <td id=<?php echo $count;?>><?php echo $row[1];?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $row[2];?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $row[3];?></td>
                   <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="insert()">register</button></td>
                   
                   </tr>
              <?php  } ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function insert()
        {
           var a = document.getElementById($count).innerHTML;
           alert(a)
        }
    </script>
    </body>
```

[image: click on the register button to get corresponding number]

Comment: Put $count=1; before the while

Comment: thanks, but that does not help, the JS function can't read $count
<script type="text/javascript">
        function insert()
        {
           var a = document.getElementById($count).innerHTML;
           alert(a)
        }
    </script>

Comment: You have to learn to ask questions. Speak clearly and address your problem. Don’t talk about unnecessary things and most importantly revise your code and do proper debug before asking. This question  could be answered with just looking at the console log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch out! Your code is wrong because you need to put the ID number instead of the PHP variable. If you want to use count you have to put it inside a PHP tag and echo it, but **you are mixing the JS with the PHP code.**

```
getElementById(<?php echo $count; ?>).innerHTML
```

Just look at the console log when you are debugging, please, that makes things a lot easier and it saves you from asking questions that you can answer yourself.

I don’t recommend that you preprocess JS however, that is an extremely bad practise for any programming language.

Comment: done that, i need a function in php, to get what ever value in $row[1], and perform other action, i dont know how to get the value by id

Comment: You are already getting the value by its id by saying row[1]. I don’t understand very much your question then

Comment: I'm saying that, i want to increment id of td, and when click on the button the id should be send to function, but not happening

Comment: You did not say anything about the button until now man! You have to explain yourself better if you want to get a real answer. Ok I will try to address your question now

Comment: Where is your insert JavaScript function definition?

Comment: thank you soo much :) done
one more thing when i click on the button it is getting second value that is the second number on the table